# Does members of class location in memory depend on the location of class members in the class definition?

Tags: c++, class, memory

I have a part of chain class

```
template <typename T> 
class Part
{
public:

part* prev;
part* next;
T data;
}
```

Size of T is undefined now and i think it must be better to place it in the end in memory.

For example, if I move 8 bytes to the right, then I’ll definitely go to the beginning of the next class member (on a 64 bit system), and if I first put T, then I don’t know where I will go. Will I influence how the class members are located in memory or the compiler will do everything as he wants?

And can i help to perfomance with use it?

Comment: The members of a class are ordered in memory as ordered in the class definition. Note that you won't just have one `Part` class. You'll have several `Part<T>` classes, each with their own layout depending on the size of `T`. It's unclear what you mean by "moving 8 bytes to the right"

Comment: In addition, there is data member padding to consider. Depending on the size of `T` and sizes of pointers, the compiler may add padding bytes to align everything properly in memory. If a class has virtual members, you also get a virtual table pointer in the class whose location is implementation-specific.

Comment: is this profitable in some cases to do fake virtual function for just adding 8 byte in memory to class object?? Or compilator dont use all what i dont ue in code?

Comment: The instance variables of a class are ordered any way the compiler wishes to order them, with the exception of PODs (which are basically in C-compatible order) and unions containing classes with same initial members.

Comment: Compiler will optimize everything in the end to the point that if a data member is not used anywhere it may be removed from the class, and all the rest of the code will be adjusted to access the right byte offsets for data member accesses. Same for unused member functions.

Comment: oh about unions, can i do union with long long int, char, char ,char and use it as colour? Will it be like 8+ 8+ 8 = 24 or all oh char will in start on bit 24 bit number?

Comment: compilers will add padding when they feel appropriate. I'd rather trust the compiler than myself

Comment: If you want to see how your data members are ordered in a particular implementation, use `offsetof(MyClass, dataMember)` with each member and see the byte offsets from the first byte where a class instance is in memory. This will help you understand how your compiler with the options you compiled the code, arranges the data members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure because it is implementation-defined between various compilers...

I added this to your code:

```
template <typename T>
class Part {
public:
    Part* prev;
    Part* next;
    T data;
};

template<typename T>
Part<T> makeClass(T value) {
   Part<T> part{};
   part.data = value;
   return part;
}

int main() {
    auto p = makeClass(12);
    return 0;
}
```

And I tested it between `x86-64 clang (trunk)`, `x86-64 gcc (trunk)` and `x64 msvc v19.24` on Compiler explorer found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/FxMHnn) all with the compiler settings set to `-std=c++17 -O3`.

If we look at the generated assembly between the three we see the following:

**Clang**

```
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

**GCC**

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

**MSVC**

```
part$ = 0
$T1 = 64
value$ = 72
Part<int> makeClass<int>(int) PROC       ; makeClass<int>, COMDAT
$LN3:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16], edx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rcx
        push    rsi
        push    rdi
        sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        lea     rax, QWORD PTR part$[rsp]
        mov     rdi, rax
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     ecx, 24
        rep stosb
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR value$[rsp]
        mov     DWORD PTR part$[rsp+16], eax
        lea     rax, QWORD PTR part$[rsp]
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR $T1[rsp]
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     ecx, 24
        rep movsb
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR $T1[rsp]
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        pop     rdi
        pop     rsi
        ret     0
Part<int> makeClass<int>(int) ENDP       ; makeClass<int>

$T1 = 32
$T2 = 56
p$ = 80
main    PROC
$LN3:
        push    rsi
        push    rdi
        sub     rsp, 120                      ; 00000078H
        mov     edx, 12
        lea     rcx, QWORD PTR $T2[rsp]
        call    Part<int> makeClass<int>(int)      ; makeClass<int>
        lea     rcx, QWORD PTR $T1[rsp]
        mov     rdi, rcx
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     ecx, 24
        rep movsb
        lea     rax, QWORD PTR p$[rsp]
        lea     rcx, QWORD PTR $T1[rsp]
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rsi, rcx
        mov     ecx, 24
        rep movsb
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 120                      ; 00000078H
        pop     rdi
        pop     rsi
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

---

Looking at the generated assembly from various compilers might help you to determine what is happening within your code and its data alignment. After looking at those values with the optimizer at level 3, change it to level 2, 1, then 1 and see the difference in the generated assembly. This might give you some insight!

A tip from the pros - trust your compiler!

Comment: the in the output of gcc and clang all the code is optimized away, so it doesnt help to see how the struct is layed out in memory

Comment: @idclev that's why I mentioned to the OP to change the level of the optimizer... then they can see what is going on.